# Error when retrieving attachment from archive using EWS 2.2 Managed API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm getting the following error when retrieving an attachment using EWS 2.2 from an Archive Mailbox:
**The request failed. Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.**

```
return _service.GetAttachments(attachmentIds, 
                               BodyType.Text, 
                               new List<PropertyDefinitionBase>{ItemSchema.MimeContent});
```

This error also happens when using the **Load** function

```
attachment.Load()
```

If I move the email outside the Archive Mailbox, I can retrieve the attachment inside the email without any problems. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this only happen on a particular attachment ? How big is the attachment ? that error indicates its a transport layer issue rather than a server issue.

Comment: Hi Glen! The attachment is 6KB. This happens when the attachment is an email. Most of the times it works fine with those attachments but there are few exceptions. And as I said, if I move that email to another mailbox that is not an archive I can retrieve the attachment inside that email without a problem.

Comment: Is this a multi threaded application ? are you accessing the Mailbox concurrently with multiple threads ? if you catch the entry and retry the operation does it work ?